# F#, Nominative or Structural Typed

Tags: f#, typing

Does F# have a Nominative Type System or a Structural Type System?

I know that OCaml is structurally typed, though F# doesn't seems to be so, is this correct?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

F# is nominative.  You can do a few structural tricks via some exotic mechanisms, but the type system of the language is primarily nominative.

Comment: If OCaml is structural, how did F# get turned around 180 degrees?

Comment: F# kinda took the functional structure and declaration syntax from OCaml, but the object type system from .NET.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162387/why-is-fs-type-inference-so-fickle/3162832#3162832

Comment: damnit, yeah...@RobertHarvey because it borrows from C# land