# Why F# fails to infer types as C# would do

Tags: f#, type-inference

From [the book by Tomas Petricek](http://www.manning.com/petricek/) the following code doesn't work as compiler is unable to infer the type of the `dt` parameter:

```
> Option.map (fun dt -> dt.Year) (Some(DateTime.Now));;
error FS0072: Lookup on object of indeterminate type.
```

And if we specify type explicitly everything works fine:

```
> Option.map (fun (dt:DateTime) -> dt.Year) (Some(DateTime.Now));;
val it : int option = Some(2008)
```

Or we can use pipelining operator to "help" compiler to infer type:

```
> Some(DateTime.Now) |> Option.map (fun dt -> dt.Year);;
val it : int option = Some(2008)
```

The question is why F# compiler can't infer the type of the `dt` parameter? In this particular case it looks quite easy to infer the `dt`'s type.

The logic behind it can be the following:

1. the signature of `Option.map` is `map : ('T -> 'U) -> 'T option -> 'U option`
2. the type of the last parameter is `DateTime option`
3. so our `map` usage looks like `map : ('T -> 'U) -> 'DateTime option -> 'U option`
4. the compiler then can try to substitute `DateTime` as `'T` to see if it would be correct, so we have `(DateTime -> 'U) -> 'DateTime option -> 'U option`
5. then it can infer the `'U` type by looking at the body of the lambda-function, so the `'U` becomes `int`
6. and we finally have `(DateTime -> int) -> 'DateTime option -> 'int option`

So why F# can't do this inference? Tomas mentions in his book that F# infers types by going from the first to the last argument and that's why the order of arguments matters. And that's why F# can't infer the types in the first example. But why F# can't behave like C#, i.e. try to infer types incrementally starting with what is known?

In most cases F# is much more powerful when speaking about type inference... that't why I'm confused a bit.

Comment: F#'s type inference is strictly top-to-bottom/left-to-right. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162387/why-is-fs-type-inference-so-fickle

Comment: The pipeline version is more idiomatic anyway

Comment: @dahlbyk The pipeline is idiomatic precisely because it is a workaround to this problem.

Answer (score 4):

> So why F# can't do this inference?

F# could do that as OCaml does that. The disadvantage of this kind of more sophisticated inference is the obfuscation of error messages. OCaml taught us that the result generated such incomprehensible errors that, in practice, you always resort to annotating types in order to prevent the compiler from being led down a type inference garden path. Consequently, there was little motivation to implement this in F# because OCaml had already shown that it is not very pragmatic.

For example, if you do that in OCaml but mis-spell the method name then you will get a huge error message at some later point in the code where two inferred class types mismatch and you will have to hunt through it to find the discrepancy and then search back through your code to find the actual location of the error.

IMO, Haskell's type classes also suffer from an equivalent practical problem.

Answer (score 0):

F# can do everything C#'s type inference can do...and much, much more. AFAIK, the extent of C#'s type inference is auto-typing a variable based on the right-hand side of an assignment.

```
var x = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

The equivalent F# would be:

```
let x = Dictionary()
```

or

```
let x = Dictionary<_,_>()
```

or

```
let x = Dictionary<string,_>()
```

or

```
let x = Dictionary<string,int>()
```

You can provide as much or as little type information as you want, but you would almost never declare the type of `x`. So, even in this simple case, F#'s type inference is obviously much more powerful. [Hindley-Milner type inference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley-Milner#algorithm) types entire programs, unifying all the expressions involved. As far as I can tell, C# type inference is limited to a single expression, assignment at that.

Comment: I'm not saying that F# type inference is weaker, I strongly believe that its much much much stronger and I've mentioned it in my question. But my question is about why F# can't infer types in the particular example from Tomas' book when it has all the power to do it. Actually the link you provided answers my question, thanks! Looks like F# language designers have decided not to make type inference too complicated to avoid possible confusions.