# The type of the common piece of Xml in different files with different scheme?

Tags: f#, type-providers, f#-data

I have the following code to deal several different xml files (different scheme) which all have node of `<parameters>`. Now I found the `match` part will be used in many place so I want to create a function for it.

```
let xml1 = XmlProvider<"./file1.xml">.Parse(resp) 
match xml1.Parameters |> Seq.tryFind (fun x -> x.Name = "token")  with
| Some value -> value.Value |> Some 
| None -> None

let xml2 = XmlProvider<"./file2.xml">.Parse(resp) // different scheme but has <parameters>
match xml2.Parameters |> Seq.tryFind (fun x -> x.Name = "token")  with
| Some value -> value.Value |> Some 
| None -> None

// more very different files but has <parameters> ......
```

In the above example you can see the `match` part is repeated. How to define the function?

```
let getToken (parameters : <what the type?>) = 
    match parameters |> Seq.tryFind (fun x -> x.Name = "token")  with
    | Some value -> value.Value |> Some 
    | None -> None
```

What the type of `parameters` should be?

**Update**: 
I've updated the question. BTW, is this a case to show the usefulness of Structural typing?

Here is the code (not workable yet) for testing. `xml1` and `xml2` have totally different xml scheme except they both have the `<parameters>` part.

```
let input1 = """<r1><parameters><parameter name="token">1</parameter><parameter name="other">xxx</parameter></parameters><othersOf1>..sample....</othersOf1></r1>"""
let xml1 = XmlProvider<"""<r1><parameters><parameter name="token">1</parameter><parameter name="other">xxx</parameter></parameters><othersOf1>...</othersOf1></r1>""">.Parse(input1)

let input2 = """<r2><parameters><parameter name="token">1</parameter><parameter name="other">xxx</parameter></parameters><othersOf2>...sample...</othersOf2></r2>"""
let xml2 = XmlProvider<"""<r2><parameters><parameter name="token">1</parameter><parameter name="other">xxx</parameter></parameters><othersOf2>...</othersOf2></r2>""">.Parse(input2)

let getToken (parameters: ????) =
    match parameters |> Seq.tryFind (fun x -> x.Name = "token")  with
    | Some value -> value.Value |> Some 
    | None -> None

let token1 = getToken xml1.Parameters
let token2 = getToken xml2.Parameters
```

Comment: Could you be looking for `Option.map`?

Comment: Your need to define the data type, then you can specify it:`type Test = XmlProvider<"./DbToken.xml">
let xml = Test.Parse(resp)` then:

Comment: `let getToken (parameters : Test.Parameters []) = 
    match parameters |> Seq.tryFind (fun x -> x.Name = "token")  with
    | Some value -> value.Value |> Some 
    | None -> None`

Comment: @FoggyFinder I've updated the question. It's more complex than I described at first.

Comment: @MarkSeemann I tried `xml.Parameters |> Option.ofObj |> Option.map (Seq.tryFind (fun x -> x.Name = "token"))` to reduce the code a little bit. However, it returns the value of `Some (Some <parameter name="token">.....</parameter>)` instead of a value of type `string option`.

Comment: you can show [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/MCVE)?

Comment: @FoggyFinder I added some code for testing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116837/discussion-between-foggy-finder-and-dc7a9163d9).

Comment: @FoggyFinder There may not be a solution in F# so I just  write the code to better ilustrate the problem.

Comment: @FoggyFinder Sorry my company network blocked the chat page.

Comment: Okay, code: https://gist.github.com/FoggyFinder/3895d8158a62f084cb9b0e0c0ab8bb48

Comment: So, as I said early - it`s not MCVE

Comment: @FoggyFinder In your example, you are using the same `type Input = XmlProvider<input>` for both examples. There will be many xml types with totally different schemes except they may all have the `parameters` part.

Comment: It was your example, not mine. That is why I asked to see MCVE ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to have a function that takes a `seq` of some type `^P` which has `Name` and `Value`. For educational purposes `Name` can be of any type `'a` (supporting equality) and `Value` is of generic type `'b`:

```
let inline get name parameters =
    parameters |> Seq.tryFind (fun x -> (^P : (member Name : 'a) x) = name)
    |> Option.map (fun v -> (^P : (member Value : 'b) v))
```

Adding some values `<parameter name="token" value="123">` to XML1 and changing name to an `int` as well having a `DateTime` value in XML2 `<parameter name="12" value="2016-12-31">` allows to get:

```
let token1 = get "token" xml1.Parameters // : int option
let token2 = get 12 xml2.Parameters // : DateTime option
```

So, yes, you are right, this can be done leveraging structural typing.

The actual type of `parameters` depends on `name` as well. The full type of `get` is:

```
name:'a -> parameters:seq< ^P> -> 'b option
  when 'a : equality and  ^P : (member get_Name :  ^P -> 'a) and
        ^P : (member get_Value :  ^P -> 'b)
```

Comment: Is the inline/Statically Resolved Type the same powerful as structural typing? How they compare?

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 Statically resolved type parameters are as far as you can get with structural typing in F#, because of F# being subject to the nominal .NET type system. Compared to e.g. OCaml this is less powerful due to (mainly, at least) the following aspects:

 - OCaml is structural typed first
 - In F# you can't declare a structural type or an alias, e.g. `type P<'a> = (^P when ^P : (member Name : 'a))` for reuse or declare an interface (e.g. in TypeScript) from which all compatible classes will automatically 'inherit'.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 See also
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162387/why-is-fs-type-inference-so-fickle/3162832#3162832, https://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/6181848-provide-better-support-for-structural-typing
https://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/6181848-provide-better-support-for-structural-typing
https://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/9633858-structural-extensible-records-like-elm-concrete
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system (OCaml example)

Comment: Thanks very much. I tested the code but I got an error so I posted another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38337854/the-type-xmlprovider-parameter-does-not-support-the-operator-get-value. Do you know why the error occurs? There should be `Value` property.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, the types of nested nodes become nested types of the type provided by the XML type provider.

To access the types, you'll first need to use a type alias and name your provided type:

```
type DbToken = XmlProvider<"""<parameters>
    <parameter name="token" value="123" />
    <parameter name="token" value="123" /> 
  </parameters>""">
```

I'm using an inline XML example, so that I can test it, but it should work the same with a file.

The type of single `<parameter />` node in the file is now `DbToken.Parameter` (name is auto-generated to be unique and may vary), so we can now write a function:

```
let getToken (parameters:DbToken.Parameter[]) = 
    match parameters |> Seq.tryFind (fun x -> x.Name = "token")  with
    | Some value -> value.Value |> Some 
    | None -> None
```

And the following call works:

```
let xml = DbToken.GetSample()    
getToken xml.Parameters
```

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the question. The xml files have different scheme but they may all have the node of `<parameters>`.

Comment: If you invoke `XmlProvider` twice, you'll get two different types - there is not much you can do about that. An alternative is to use `SampleIsList` parameter (http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/reference/fsharp-data-xmlprovider.html) to specify multiple different examples to the provider - then the types will be shared (if you also set `Global=true`, the provider will unify types based on tag names).