# The type 'XmlProvider<...>.Parameter' does not support the operator 'get_Value'?

Tags: f#, f#-data

How to fix the code? Is the inline/Statically Resolved Type the same powerful as structural typing?

> The type 'XmlProvider<...>.Parameter' does not support the operator 'get_Value'?

```
let input1 = """<r1><parameters><parameter name="token">1</parameter><parameter name="other">xxx</parameter></parameters><othersOf1>..sample....</othersOf1></r1>"""
let xml1 = XmlProvider<"""<r1><parameters><parameter name="token">1</parameter><parameter name="other">xxx</parameter></parameters><othersOf1>...</othersOf1></r1>""">.Parse(input1)

let inline get name parameters =
    parameters |> Seq.tryFind (fun x -> (^P : (member Name : 'a) x) = name)
    |> Option.map (fun v -> (^P : (member Value : 'b) v))

get "token" xml1.Parameters
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Value` is only defined for nodes that have a single type (or types the type provider can unify, e.g. 2 and 3.0). In your example the second value is the string `xxx`, so a parameter gets *two* properties: `Number` and `String`, each returning an `option` of the respective type. You can either

- change your input to have *one single* consistent value type (`xxx` → `2`)

  ```
  let xml1 = XmlProvider<"""<r1><parameters><parameter name="token">1</parameter><parameter name="other">2</parameter></parameters><othersOf1>...</othersOf1></r1>""">.Parse(input1)
  ```
- turn them into a single output type (e.g. `string`)

  ```
  let inline get name parameters =
      parameters |> Seq.tryFind (fun x -> (^P : (member Name : 'a) x) = name)
      |> Option.bind (fun v ->
          match (^P : (member Number : int option) v) with
          | Some number -> Some (string number)
          | None -> (^P : (member String : string option) v))
  ```
- create an appropriate DU

  ```
  type Value = Number of int | Name of string

  let inline get name parameters =
      parameters |> Seq.tryFind (fun x -> (^P : (member Name : 'a) x) = name)
      |> Option.map (fun v ->
          match (^P : (member Number : int option) v) with
          | Some number -> Number number
          | None ->
              match (^P : (member String : string option) v) with
              | Some s -> Name s
              | _ -> failwith "Either number or string should be Some(value)")
  ```
- if you don't know the values upfront, you can also tell the type provider to *not* infer them at all:

  ```
  XmlProvider<"""...""", InferTypesFromValues=false>
  ```

  this will cause `parameters` to have a `Value : string` property.

Comment: Thanks, this works when the token is `1`. However, it fails when I test it after change `1` to `a1`. The real input can be text which cannot be converted to a number.

Comment: Yes, then you have `Value` again, because all values are just `string`s.
You need to have a *representative* sample of your input to have a suitable type generated.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 see last added option

Comment: Yes, the last option is perfect. Because I may just use the downloaded xml file to feed Xml type provider. And a lot of time I would like just treat the xml inner text as text.