# How to support structurally-typed in a nominal-typed language?

Tags: c#, .net, f#, functional-programming, ocaml

In [F#, Nominative or Structural?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3137512/7821462), the answer said that I can trick F# to work like a structurally-typed language via some exotic mechanisms. How can I do so?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "exotic mechanism" that the previous answer refers to is probably [statically resolved type parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/generics/statically-resolved-type-parameters). This lets you write functions that take object of any type that has some specific member. For example, you can write `sayHello` function that will work with any object that has a `Name` member of type `string`:

```
let inline sayHello (any : ^T) = 
  let name = (^T : (member Name : string) any)
  printfn "Hello %s" name
```

This will now work with two types that are nominally unrelated:

```
type Person(name:string) = 
  member x.Name = name

type Animal(name:string) = 
  member x.Name = name

sayHello (Person("Tomas"))
sayHello (Animal("Bunny"))
```

That said, F# is primarily a nominally typed language and so relying on static member constraints too much would be unidiomatic. It will make your code look bad and you'll likely hit limitations of the mechanism. It is a nice feature for *some* limited use cases, but it's not a primary abstraction mechanism in F#.

Comment: He said "mechanism*s*" so are there other tricks beside statically resolved type parameters?

Comment: I guess there are other cases where F# behaves structurally (e.g. computation expression builders), but as far as I can think, static member constraints and their various uses are the only obviously structural thing in F#.

Comment: Neat how you add the member to any. Tried shortcutting, but
`let inline sayHello (any : ^T when ^T : (member Name : string)) = printfn "Hello %s" any.Name` doesn't seem to cut it.

Comment: @Funk Yeah, that's one of the limitations - the calls are ugly :)